# Replacing an html character after the output of a php script?

Tags: php, html

I am using a rating system on my site and I call for the value "4_5" in php.

Example:

`<span class="rating"><?php echo $meta['rating']; ?></span>`

Is there a way I could use this...

`$name = str_replace('_', '.', $name);`

to replace the underscore after calling for it?

PS. I'm very new at php and html but have searched for this everywhere!

Comment: Why don't you do that prior the `echo` ?

Comment: Sincerely, I don't understand your question... what problem do you have? str_replace is not working for you?

Comment: I wonder why you store the value as `4_5` rather than `4.5` in the first place...

Comment: This problem is an example of why you should use frameworks/templates and NOT place logic into views ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify a value in PHP after you echoed it. 
But you don't even need to, because you can use the str_replace around your $meta['rating'] like this:

```
<span class="rating"><?php echo str_replace('_', '.', $meta['rating']); ?></span>
```

This will display 4_5 as 4.5

Comment: Well....with output buffering you can, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, worked perfectly. I wish I could have used 4.5 as the value, but css made me use 4_5 because the value also accounts for visual rating stars.